Is the value href in the base tag for reference only or points to a URL that must exist?
I once had a webpage where I set the href value of the base tag to the path where most links start with that path, but the href value isn't supposed to point to an actual page.
Here's an example of what I mean with a few links:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/folder/">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="one">Link to /folder/one/</a><br>
    <a href="two">Link to /folder/two/</a><br>
    <a href="three">Link to /folder/three/</a><br>
    <a href="http://example.com/">Link to outside website</a><br>
</body>
</html>

I ran a page like this through an seo tool. They checked all the regular links including the string in the base tag (which in this example is /folder/)
I always thought the base tag was only used to define the base folder where links on the page come from if they don't have an absolute folder set.
Or is it true that now the base tag defines a link that is supposed to be accessible as well?

The example given by w3c's documentation is
<base href="https://www.example.com/news/index.html">

so they are pointing to an existing page, not a folder.
They say the href value must be a valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces, which isn't particularly clear whether a validly structured URL that returns a 404 still counts.  I would not rely on SEO tools to always know themselves, but this would explain why some tools may check it's validity by seeing what response the link throws.
Probably good practise to put something at /folder/, anyway, as users would expect to find content there.
